# Backup large postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, backup

I have a 160 Gb database on 200 Gb hard drive, so I need to make a dump of this base. When I use pg_dump I ran out of free space. Are there any methods to make backup by parts? Thank in advance.

Comment: You can dump individual tables (or schemas) with pg_dump

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Well, I have 728 tables in my db... Can I make backup of 5 most large tables, and then backup others using --exclude? And how to combine this together afterwards?

Comment: You can dump from (and: to) a remote machine with sufficient diskspace.